# Error: variable not defined

Tags: python-2.7

The code below is a simple dice throwing program. Is it important to define x? Also when I define x='a' the program is not working as expected. When user inputs 'n' the while loop does not exit. Below is the code:

```
    from random import randint  
    while x != 'N' or x != 'n':  
       rand = randint(1, 6)  
       print "Your new dice number is: " + str(rand)   
       x = raw_input("Do you want to roll again?(y/n): ")
```

Comment: At first, your program doesn't have assigned any value of variable X before while loop.

Comment: I did assign x = 'a'. And although the program executes in pycharm but the loop doesn't exit when the user inputs 'n' or 'N'.

Comment: Because of bad logic in your while loop - see my answer below.

Comment: @Crossfit_Jesus did any of the answers worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing like:

```
from random import randint
x = "y"
while True:
   rand = randint(1, 6)
   print "Your new dice number is: " + str(rand)
   x = raw_input("Do you want to roll again?(y/n): ")
   if(x == "Y" or x == "y"):
       continue
   elif( x == "n" or x == "N"):
       break
   else:
       print "Unknown Input"
       break
```

and the loop wasn't breaking because in your code you have not put the `break` statement if user inputs 'N' or 'n'

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
```

you have to assign a value to variable X before while loop:

```
x='s'
```

and second problem with your program is logic in while loop (try to think why it isn't working properly in your case)

```
while not (x == 'N' or x == 'n'):
    rand = randint(1, 6)
    print "Your new dice number is: " + str(rand)
    x = raw_input("Do you want to roll again?(y/n): ")
```

Comment: shouldn't you check for `Y` condition as well ?

Comment: @warl0ck but what should happen when it is not 'Y' nor 'N' ?

Comment: I know that has nothing to do with error but just following good practices :)